# how to read from the xml node using c# as per my requirement

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Here is my xml code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xd:xmldiff version="1.0" srcDocHash="11928043053884448382" options="IgnoreChildOrder IgnoreNamespaces IgnoreWhitespace IgnoreXmlDecl " fragments="no" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xmltools/2002/xmldiff">
    <xd:node match="2">
        <xd:node match="2">
            <xd:node match="19">
                <xd:node match="2">
                    <xd:add>Y</xd:add>
                </xd:node>
            </xd:node>
            <xd:add match="/2/2/11" opid="2" />
            <xd:change match="18" name="OWNINGSITE">
                <xd:node match="2">
                    <xd:remove match="1" />
                </xd:node>
            </xd:change>
            <xd:add match="/2/2/2-9" opid="1" />
            <xd:change match="17" name="STATUS">
                <xd:node match="2">
                    <xd:remove match="1" />
                </xd:node>
            </xd:change>
            <xd:remove match="14-16" />
            <xd:remove match="13" subtree="no">
                <xd:remove match="1-2" />
            </xd:remove>
            <xd:remove match="11" opid="2" />
            <xd:remove match="10" />
            <xd:remove match="2-9" opid="1" />
            <xd:remove match="1" />
        </xd:node>
        <xd:node match="5">
            <xd:node match="3">
                <xd:node match="11">
                    <xd:change match="1">0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1</xd:change>
                </xd:node>
            </xd:node>
        </xd:node>
    </xd:node>
    <xd:descriptor opid="1" type="move" />
    <xd:descriptor opid="2" type="move" />
</xd:xmldiff>
```

I have written a c# code to parse through each node and get the value of match. I am unable to figure out how to parse through the nodes to get the values of all the matches. While debugging the code I found out that nodelist is not recieving the appropriate value through "xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/node");" due to which foreach is not getting executed at all. Is my usage of "/node" right to get the values of its attribute "match"?

```
namespace demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load("C:\\shreyas\\NX_Temp\\NX_Temp\\000048_A\\CompareReport3D.xml");
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/node");
            string[] arr1 = new string[10];
            int i = 0;

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                 arr1[i] = node.Attributes["match"].Value;
                 i++;
            }

            i = 0;
            while (arr1[i] != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the String=" + arr1[i]+ ":" + arr1[i++]+ ":" + arr1[i++]+":" + arr1[i++]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I need to find the values of "match" in the form of string

output should be:
`the String = 2:2:19:2`

Comment: Please provide a more detailed sample output for your example. I cannot understand what exactly the result of your program should be.

Comment: Hi, I have made few changes to the code and added the sample output

Comment: So, should it output the path made of "match" values for each node that has no children?

Comment: yeah it should get match values

Comment: Do you get an error or is the output false? I see some strange things in the while loop, but I'm not sure what your precise problem is

Comment: The output i mentioned is the output i want to get. Right now I am getting an error

Comment: What kind of an error?

Comment: While debugging the code I found out that nodelist is not recieving the appropriate value throught "xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/node");" due to which foreach is not getting executed at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# XmlDocument SelectNodes is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889895/c-sharp-xmldocument-selectnodes-is-not-working)

Comment: But here I want to know whether  the usage of "/node" in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/node"); is right to get the values of its attribute "match"

Comment: Maybe you need to do `xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/xd:node")`. I also kind of get the feeling that this isn't the entire XML, because I miss the first line. But in the basis it is the same question, that's why I marked it as a duplicate

Comment: i added the entire xml now

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use recursion.

Write a function that takes an `XmlNode node`, a `string currentPath` and a `List<string> paths`. It should:

1. append the `match` attribute of `node` to the `currentPath` and check if the `node` has children that are `node`s.
2. If there's no children, it adds `currentPath` to `paths` and returns.
3. If there are children, it calls itself for each child by passing child, `currentPath` (which has been modified) and `paths`.

To start, you will call this function with the root node, an empty string and an empty list. When the function completes, the formerly empty list will contain your paths, e.g. two paths for your example:

- "2:2:19:2"
- "2:5:3:11"

Comment: Thanks Alexey :) but I am unable to understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex to match all the attributes you are looking for:

```
// Find all attributes that match the pattern match="x" - where x can be any value.
foreach (var match in Regex.Matches(str, "match=\"([^\"]+)\""))
{
    // For each match, match only the "x" part of the result and remove the containing ".
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(match.ToString(), "\"([^\"]+)\"").ToString()
        .Replace("\"", string.Empty));
}
```