# Reading XML Yields no Results

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to enumerate this xml (sample):

```
<SearchSuggestion xmlns="http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2" version="2.0">
   <Query xml:space="preserve">Relativity</Query>
   <Section>
    <Item>
        <Text xml:space="preserve">Relativity</Text>
        <Url xml:space="preserve">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity</Url>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Text xml:space="preserve">Relativity priority dispute</Text>
        <Url xml:space="preserve">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_priority_dispute</Url>
    </Item>
....
```

using:

```
XmlNodeList nItems = rssDoc.SelectNodes("/SearchSuggestion/Section/Item")
```

But it is yielding no results. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Maybe this question is related to yours?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889895/c-sharp-xmldocument-selectnodes-is-not-working

Comment: I strongly suspect it's due to the namespaces. It's fixable with XPath, but I'd personally suggest using LINQ to XML instead - that tends to be simpler in terms of namespace handling, IMO.

Comment: And, here is documentation from Microsoft, hope that helps.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You have a default namespace `xmlns="http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2"` so follow the instructions from [Using Xpath With Default Namespace in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/585812/3744182).

Comment: Thanks. The simple string replace worked a treat